# Cassandra Performance Tuning

Tags: cassandra, ycsb

I have successfully installed a multi-node Cassandra cluster with 10nodes,
The nodetool status command shows every node is UP and NORMAL.

but the Performance I am getting is very bad.

here are my results:

```
Operations /seconds = 4000
Read Latency = 13ms
write Latency = 10ms
```

I am using YCSB to measure performance

Tuning that I have done till now:

```
Consistency level = 1
Replication Factor = 3
Heap size = 4GB
```

My Hardware:
Each node is a VM with CentOS

```
2GHZ CPU with 8 cores
8GB RAM
1GB/ps N/W
```

Please let me know what more settings I can tweak to get maximum performance out of my cluster.

Comment: What does the physical hardware look like? Do the VMs have to share resources (CPU, RAM, disks, NICs)?

Comment: @Ralf 
Yes the VM's share the resources,

The total RAM is 64GB, I have assigned 8GB/ RAM to each VM

The CPU and NIC are shared.

Comment: Running all C* nodes on a single physical machine will yield hardly any horizontal scaling and no hardware failure tolerance at all. All nodes compete for the same resources. In particular the disks, which are probably your bottleneck.

Comment: @Ralf
I do not think the Disks can be a bottleneck because:
i) I am using NetApp Storage Controller with SAS Disks (So I have enough disks)

ii)I have checked using nmon ,
The CPU utilization is ~60% even with YCSB running at 200 threads
Memory utilization is ~50%


Can there be any other cause of bottleneck ?
or some Cassandra configuration that I may have missed?

Comment: What OS? What version of C*? what version/branch of ycsb?

Comment: @ChrisLohfink

Its CentOS 7, C* 2.1 , YCSB 0.7.0 with Cassandra-CQL2

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1 system with 10 VMs running on it and 1 disk, the performance of any (not in-memory) database will be bad. *Especially* with spinning disks (no matter how expensive they are) is going to be a major contention point. With a really good SSD you may be able to pull off a few instances, but performance stress testing will likely always hit either that or a CPU bottleneck (if things configured correctly for system).

Pretty good chance with 4gb heaps and a stress workload you are going to be hitting GC and memory issues, do you have any monitoring around that? Can use visualvm and connect to the `ip:7199` (ip set in `cassandra-env.sh`).

8gb of ram per vm is on the minimum spec end. You want at least 8gb of JVM heap with space for the offheap stuff and OS. A 16gb system is likely sufficient. Once again the shared disk will kill performance so it will only go so far. but should be able to do far better than 4k/sec.

Comment: But I have storage controller attached to the server via FiberChannel connectivity.(16 x 600GB SAS Disks).

There is no CPU bottleneck as I am using nmon to monitor the CPU and it is still 60% used when YCSB is running.

I understand that I am using VM's and the performance will take a hit but still 4000 Operations / seconds is tooo low ,

I will check the GC now and update here.

Comment: i suspect the low heap is your immediate bottleneck. Could you try with 5 nodes and double the size of OS memory/heaps? the default jvm heap settings for 8gb is pretty good.